# memset after malloc

Tags: c, linux, memory, malloc, memset

I have three lines (version) of a linux product. V1 works fine in the customer. V2 and V3
crashed and the fix seems to be a memset call after a malloc call.

What is the deeper explanation on this topic? Why memset resolved the issue?

Comment: My car is broken, it seems that after I start it it doesn't work. My friend has the same car and it doesn't break. What's the problem? - Please add some code, we are not prophets.

Comment: @cnicutar did it crashe in V1?

Comment: @dark_charlie, it looks like that some user do not need code.

Comment: There is no rule in SO community that mandates to append code in a question. Company rules do not allow to paste code here. Anyway...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess without a code example is that you were operating on the buffer or struct you malloc'd with assumptions that its contents would be initialized with certain default values.  Malloc doesn't initialize the memory it hands back, so unless you memset or use some other initialization, the values in that memory could be anything, and therefore, if you're trying to check a pointer assuming it'd be NULL or that an int will be zero, you can't make that assumption without initializing the memory first.

Comment: Thanks. Your guess helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because there is a wrong assumtion that the allocated buffer is zeroed. So for example if the buffer contains a string and is printed somewhere before initialize, it can result in an access violation. Zeroing the buffer would fix such an issue.